# What happens to All Access albums in my library when I unsubscribe from Google All Access?

Tags: google-play-music

So, I added a few albums from Google All Access to my Google Music library. When I look at my library, I cannot tell the difference between albums I purchased (prior to my All Access subscription) and albums added from All Access. If I unsubscribe from All Access, what happens to the albums I added to my library from All Access?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what happened to me today:

My free trial finished and I lost all my All-Access tracks from my Library and Playlists.

When I called Google's Support they told me the tracks would re-appear whenever I paid the monthly fee, so I did it and fortunately it worked!

Still I don't know how to distinguish between All-Access and Purchased/Uploaded tracks.

I created a similar post: [Google Play Music: How can I distinguish between Purchased/Uploaded and All-Access tracks?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54157/google-play-music-how-can-i-distinguish-between-purchased-uploaded-and-all-acce)

Regards!